# ASP.NET can not find HttpUtility

Tags: c#, asp.net, urlencode

> The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context.

I'm a bit stuck here. I have `using System.Web` at the top of my file, which has no error, and `System.Web` is listed in my references. I tried double-clicking the reference, finding the `UrlEncode` method in the object browser, and literally drag-and-dropping the method into my code, and it still can't find `HttpUtility`. What am I missing?

Here is the code, boiled down:

```
using System.Web
```

---

```
string path = "path/to/file";
path = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path);
```

Fully qualifying HttpUtility doesn't help either. It doesn't even show up in the auto-complete list. Only "AspNetHostingPermission" shows up.

Comment: Do you have this living in an `HttpUtility` namespace or class?

Comment: can you copy and paste your code? Would help to see what you're dealing with.

Comment: The System assembly comes with items in the System.Web namespace. I think you won't see the "HttpUtility" class until you have a reference to System.Web. Does your project have a reference to System.Web in the References?

Comment: @Splash-X, did you read the question?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It is not uncommon for people to THINK they have referenced System.Web since the System assembly ships with items in the System.Web namespace. It never hurts to ask if infact the reference was created.

Comment: Is it a Console application? If yes, switch 'net 4 client profile' to 'net 4', it's a common issue. Otherwise double check the reference.

Comment: did you try fully-qualifying that class: `System.Web.HttpUtility`? You may be having a mess at the `using` list.

Comment: Indeed, fully qualifying still won't see it. My using list is pretty small, just the usual you would have in an MVC app.

Comment: Have you tried clean and then rebuild on the project?

Comment: @directedition What classes or other namespaces do you see under System.Web? Are there several or just 3 (AspNetHostingPermission, AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute, AspNetHostingPermissionLevel)?

Comment: @Spash-X just the three.

Comment: If you right click the System.Web reference, what does Path, resolved, runtime version, etc show?  Also did you have to add the reference to System.Web or was it automatically added when you created the project?

And what does your project output type show on the properties->application tab?  is it set to Class Library?

Comment: @directedition Are you positive you did add a reference to "System.Web.dll" by going to Project => Add Reference => .Net Tab, selecting System.Web? The three classes I listed are all part of the System.dll assembly, NOT System.Web.dll. The System.dll assembly exposes the System.Web namespace (your using System.Web;) but without referencing the System.Web.dll you wont gain access to all the goodies that the System.Web.dll offers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look to me like you have another library in your solutions and that's where you are trying to access the HttpUtility. If that's correct, you need to add a reference to System.Web dll in your library.

Let me know if that was the case.

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Thanks! :S The project lived happily ever after.

Comment: Just as a note for future visitors, if you only see AspNetHostingPermission, AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute, AspNetHostingPermissionLevel under System.Web you only have a reference to System.dll and need to add a reference to System.Web.dll.

Comment: That was it for me - obvious  now!