# issue escaping charceter for json using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, json.net

Trying to escape special characters for json using following code

```
Dim testString As String = "this ""word"" is escaped"

Dim retruString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(testString, "\\([^""\\/bfnrtu])", "\\")
```

I know I have overlooked something really silly or maybe its been a long day/night, if anyone can point to my mistake would be greatly thankful

There is no error but the `retruString` is not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4, you do not need a regex:

```
retruString = System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(testString)
```

For older .NET versions, check out this post: [How to escape JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242118/how-to-escape-json-string)

Comment: I was unable to find HttpUtility , and I am currently running .NET 4.5, How does it affects the string ? can you give an example please ?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183435/asp-net-can-not-find-httputility